# Python command for QGIS that iterates over .xyz files doesn't work

Tags: pyqgis, syntaxerror

I have a small Python script for QGIS that goes to a folder and iterates over its files and uploads all .xyz files. This is the script:

```
import glob, os    

dir = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\xyz_daten"

os.chdir(dir)

for file in glob.glob("*.xyz"):
    uri = "file:///" + dir + file + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4647&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (" ", "field_1", "field_2")
    name = file.replace('.xyz', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, "delimitedtext")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

unfortunately I get the following error message right under the first line :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 6
    import glob, os
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid Syntax
```

but where is the syntax error and how would it be correct?

Comment: If you run a script with a single line of code, which is `import glob,os`, what happens? Where are you running this script from?

Comment: If `import glob, os` is the line 6, what is in the line 5?

Comment: Are `glob` and `os` installed on your PC? As was suggested by @Gabriel De Luca, what do you have above the line 6?